# How to clear frame info in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, reset

I  have the code like so to show the widget info:

```
for widget in base_frame.winfo_children():
    print(widget)
```

produces this:

```
.!frame.!label
.!frame.!label2
.!frame.!frame
.!frame.!label3
.!frame.!label4
.!frame.!frame2
.!frame.!label5
.!frame.!label6
.!frame.!frame3
```

Trying to reset the frames, I have tried destroying all the child frames

```
frame_a.destroy()
frame_b.destroy()
frame_c.destroy()
```

in the base_frame which correspond to !frame1, !frame2, and !frame3 respectively,
and then recreate them:

```
a_frame = tkinter.Frame(base_frame, background="green")
a_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ew', rowspan=2)
.
.
.
```

But the next time I destroy and reset, and run my code again it increments the frame#:

```
.!frame.!label
.!frame.!label2
.!frame.!label3
.!frame.!label4
.!frame.!label5
.!frame.!label6
.!frame.!frame4
.!frame.!frame5
.!frame.!frame6
```

Specifically I want to prevent the frame numbers from incrementing. Can't seem to find a method to do this unless destroying the base_frame. Thanks for any help.

Comment: It cannot be done as `.!frame.!frame` (for example) points to the destroyed frame and `tkinter` doesn't free this name for reuse. I don't know the context for such a need but you may be able to enumerate the widgets yourself for output.

Comment: The internal frame number is irrelevant. As long as you have a reference to the frame, you don't need the internal number. Please provide a [mcve].